# Mpi4Py - sending numpy subarray (non-contiguous memory) without copy

Tags: arrays, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I am rewriting communication bottleneck. I need to send sub-arrays of 3d `numpy` arrays.
But passing the sub-array directly to `MPI.Send()` fails with:

```
ValueError: ndarray is not contiguous
```

Creating new datatype by `MPI.Datatype.Create_vector` does not help - it fails from the same reason.

Simplified example:

```
a = numpy.zeros([9,9])
sub = a[3:5, 3:5]

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

t = MPI.DOUBLE.Create_vector(2, 2, 9)
t.Commit()

if rank == 0:
    sub.flat[:] = range(1,9)
    comm.Send([sub, t], dest=1)
else:
    comm.Recv([sub, t], source=0)
```

In actual code I use asynchronous sends/receives. Currently I solve it by copying the sub-array to temporary array with contiguous memory layout.

Problem is that the buffers tend to be pretty large and it eats all the memory and available swap.

I think that creating strided datatype is a way to go, but as I do not have access to the original array with contiguous memory I cannot create the strided buffer.

Also using the lower case version of send/recv is not an option, because as I said I need speed and the data are big.

Currently only idea I have is to create C module extension, where I do all the pointer calculation and return back numpy array with access to the contiguous memory segment containing my sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question unanswered when I faced this same issue. You can use `Create_subarray(sizes, subsizes, starts, int order=ORDER_C)` to get this done:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

a = np.zeros([9, 9])

if rank == 0:
    a[3:5, 3:5] = np.ones([2, 2])

t = MPI.DOUBLE.Create_subarray([9, 9], [2, 2], [3, 3])
t.Commit()

if rank == 0:
    comm.Send([a, t], dest=1)
else:
    comm.Recv([a, t], source=0)
```

**Extra tip:** From what I could see, the documentation of `mpi4py` is very scant. I could not find any help on creating derived datatypes with `mpi4py` online. If you want to see the list of datatypes you can create with `mpi4py`, run the following at the Python console:

```
>>> from mpi4py import MPI
>>> help(MPI.DOUBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (that also allows to have the same MPI.Datatype for an arbitrary sub-vector)

```
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI

size = 9
subsize = 2
start = 1

a = numpy.zeros([size,size])

t = MPI.DOUBLE.Create_vector(subsize, subsize, size)
t.Commit()

# 2D index to 1D index 
begin = start * size + start
end = begin + t.Get_extent()[1] // a.itemsize

if MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank() == 0:
    a[start : start + subsize, start : start + subsize] = 2
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send([a.reshape(size * size)[begin:end], t], dest=1)
else:
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv([a.reshape(size * size)[begin:end], t], source=0)
    print(a)
```

output:

```
$ mpirun -n 2 python src/python/test.py
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 2.]
 [0. 2. 2.]]
```